# Taking maximum value form custom html in textarea via jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have `textarea` and some custom HTML within it. I am able to access all the values, but I want to extract out the maximum value from it. I don't know what jQuery code I should use for this.

Please take a look at my code and give me your valuable suggestions.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const $peaks = $("<div/>").html($('.textarea').val()).find("Peak");
  var maxval = $peaks.eq(0).text();
  alert(maxval);
});
// output should be 49.0
```

```html
<textarea class='textarea'>
<Peak n="7" hkl="-1 1 0" d="1.2280">32.0%</Peak>
<Peak n="8" hkl="2 3 2" d="1.1893">10.0%</Peak>
<Peak n="9" hkl="1 2 0" d="1.1529">49.0%</Peak>
<Peak n="10" hkl="3 3 3" d="1.1157">7.0%</Peak>
</textarea>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the maximum value from the elements in `$peaks` you can first use `map()` to build an array of their values as floats, then `Math.max()` to get the highest one. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const $peaks = $("<div/>").html($('.textarea').val()).find("Peak");
  let values = $peaks.map((i, el) => parseFloat(el.textContent.trim())).get();
  let maxval = Math.max.apply(null, values);
  console.log(maxval);
});
// output should be 49.0
```

```html
<textarea class='textarea'>
<Peak n="7" hkl="-1 1 0" d="1.2280">32.0%</Peak>
<Peak n="8" hkl="2 3 2" d="1.1893">10.0%</Peak>
<Peak n="9" hkl="1 2 0" d="1.1529">49.0%</Peak>
<Peak n="10" hkl="3 3 3" d="1.1157">7.0%</Peak>
</textarea>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```